# problem in logging out from drawer navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I am trying to logout from drawer navigator to go back to '**login**' screen but not able to dod so 
i have a stack navigator in **app.js** where i have added dashboad (i.e drawer navigator) and login also 
from login i am able to navigate to dashboard but from dashboard which has a drawer navigator is not going back to login page

*Login.js*

```
checkLogin() {
    const {username,password}=this.state
    if(username=="user" && password=="user")
    {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('dashboard')
    }
```

*Dashboard.js*

```
 class Dashboard extends Component{


    static navigationOptions ={
        header:null,

    }

}
onLogout = () => {
    console.log('sign out');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
```

calling--

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor='lightgrey'activeOpacity={0.8} 
             onPress={this.onLogout}>
```

*app.js*

```
 const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Splash:Splash,
    login: Login,
    signup:Signup,
    dashboard:Dashboard,  
    dealerDashboard:DealerDashboard

  });
  const App = createAppContainer (MainNavigator);
```

Comment: which version of react-navigation are you using ?

Comment: "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.2",